# Serial resistors in matrix keypads: what is the purpose?

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, integrated-circuit

I have seen in some schematics of matrix keypads the use of serial resistors.
I understand that this is to limit the current, but why?

Here is an example, where you can see that 470 ohm serial resistors are in use:

[image: Example of schematic]

Than you!

Comment: The answer may depend on where the pins are connected (which MCU) to and what kind of code is driving the pins. Would you care to add that information in to the question?

Comment: http://sxlist.com/TECHREF/parallax/sxb/sxb/ex_4x4_keypad.htm

Answer (score 17):

The keyboard you show is typically connected as:

- RC.[7:4] to logic inputs
- RC.[3:0] to logic outputs, all lines LOW except one HIGH to select a ROW

If multiple column keys are pressed, then RC.[3:0] pins can be shorted together, straining the logic outputs. The 470R resistors would limit this current. It could possibly produce an illegal logic voltage for the RC[7:4] inputs but logic drivers often aren't balanced, LOW drive strength being different to HIGH drive strength, so they may well not.

Other solutions that wouldn't need the resistors are:

- Drive RC.[3:0] with all lines tri-state except one HIGH to select a ROW
- Use diodes in place of the 470R resistors (A=RC.x, K=switch)

Both these solutions drive the not-scanned rows at high impedance instead of LOW.

Answer (score 7):

Your question is missing a lot of information, so this is only a guess . . .

RC4 - RC7 probably are inputs (?), which is why they have pull-down resistors.  This means that RC0 - RC3 are outputs (?).  If two or more buttons in the same column are pressed at the same time, a high output could be connected to a low output - not a good thing.

Comment: This. I have actually seen real device that had row GPIO pin broken, probably for this exact reason. Another way to avoid this is to use open-drain outputs and pull-ups on the inputs, then series resistors are not needed.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, the 470 Ohms could be eliminated, but the switched capacitance might create a spike currents but steady-state current is limited by the 10k pull-down. So there must have been a good reason to avoid interference.

**added:**
I believe the trace inductance and low impedance drive could trigger some current in the high-side ESD protection diodes so adding the resistors would certain dampen and prevent that on the input side. This could be simulated but perhaps added for unknown targets as a conservative damping resistor to the step voltage.

Classic Matrix array 4x4 scanning with an 8 bit port.

- NO, normally open = 0 Pull down big R.
- Closed = 1 from driving row high with smaller R.

Scan 4 rows and read 4 columns.

[image]

Comment: Nothing in this answer is incorrect, it just is basic matrix-scan information and doesn't attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @BenVoigt I agree if you are challenged in reading timing diagrams, otherwise disagree as the resistor ratios permit the voltage changes. Should I explain how a voltage divider works with a switch?  Actually switching capacitance the 470 ohm does limit current

Comment: Your timing diagram would be equally valid if those series resistors were removed (to short circuit, not open circuit).  Limiting current into a capacitance is at least relevant to the presence of the series resistance.

Comment: agreed, thanks for your feedback @BenVoigt  so I elaborated on your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is that the series resistors are meant to protect the MCU from newbie programming or wiring errors.

Sometimes on some developement boards a single GPIO pin has been used for multiple purposes, so if the pins are shared with for example data pins of an LCD module, pushing two buttons on same column would short two rows together which can corrupt LCD data. So this allows the pins to be shared. If this circuit exists in isolation, it may have been copied from such a board without seeing that used only for one purpose the resistors may not be needed.

Even a better assumption may be that the program to scan the matrix was made by someone who did not know that better methods than just setting the GPIO ports as push-pull outputs exist and the resistors keep the pins from shorting together.

Edit: As the original source for the diagram and source code was found and posted in the comments, it's rather clear my assumptions about software just setting rows as push-pull outputs were correct. Technically, it might be better to keep other rows as high-impedance inputs and only push the scanned row high.